# (How) Does the compiler compile a monolithic program as a threaded one?

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-construction

I wrote a monolithic designed program which is quite rough on the processors needs. And as I have a dual-core I figured that one CPU should therefore be always at 100%. But both my CPUs are on 100% all the time. Now I am guessing that my compiler somehow turned my monolithic application in a threaded one. What are the limits of those optimization feature and when is it still needed to explicit make something threaded?

I am using the gcc on Ubuntu linux 64-Bit

Comment: Your assumption sounds faulty.

Comment: Are you sure it's your program that's using both CPUs?

Comment: but why should my program than use on both CPUs 100% of the capacity if i did not implement any threading at all?

Comment: @eran quite sure, when my program is not running both CPUs are at 20% of usage.

Comment: Antivirus? Disk encryption? Disk compression? Is your program disk I/O  based or what? Are you accessing SQL or other "services" on your machine? Are you using a GC for C++?

Comment: @Sim: Have you used something like [`top(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) to verify that it is fact your program's process that is taking up both CPUs at 100%?

Comment: It can also depend on what your program does. If you are streaming massive amounts of data to stdout, you could be pegging the terminal emulator and graphics environment, too. I see this now and then.

Comment: @Adam, thank you didn't know of that shelltool, it showed that XORG jumps as soon as my program runs probably because of its fast output. I did run there in quite a mis assumption thank you. If you put it out as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: @Sim: Assuming you're using normal Ubuntu, the gnome system monitor which I assume you were using to see that CPU usage does also have a per-process view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, at least not without using something like [Cilk](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cilk/).  You must be inadvertently using multiple threads (or processes) without realizing it.  Perhaps you're using a third-party library that creates an extra thread or two in your process?

**[EDIT]**

As per the comments, use a program like [`top(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) to verify that is in fact your program's process that is using both CPUs at 100%.  In your case, the XORG process is jumping to 100% because your program is producing a large amount of output.

Comment: I am just using the STL-Container everything else I did implement on my own

Answer (score 1):

Any calls to the OS, or other libraries (CRT for instance) may use other threads as well.  I would hardly be surprised if the console ran in it's own thread, and if you're doing a lot of IO of any sort, that could cause the other CPU to max out.